# Typescript async/await cannot determine correct return type

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have the following Promise-based method in Typescript:

```js
filterByParams(
  query: Aggregate<any[]>,
  params: ParamsObject
): Promise<Aggregate<any[]>> {
  return this.findSomething(params)
    .then<Aggregate<any[]>>((results: SomeResultType[]) => {
      const matcher = {
        // ... using results to match something
      };

      return query.match(matcher);
    });
}
```

The method basically adds a filter to a (mongoose) aggregate, based on the result from another query.

This works perfectly fine and Typescript is happy.

#### Problem

If I try to convert this to use the async/await pattern, Typescript starts to complain. Here is the converted method:

```js
async filterByParams(
  query: Aggregate<any[]>,
  params: ParamsObject
): Promise<Aggregate<any[]>> {
  const results: SomeResultType[] = await this.findSomething(params);

  const matcher = {
    // ... using results to match something
  };

  return query.match(matcher);
}
```

This time I get a compilation error from Typescript, on the `return ...`-line, telling me:

> TS2322: Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Aggregate< any[]>'

It seems like Typescript somehow cannot infer the correct return type from the `query.match(matcher)` function, and even casting it to `as Aggregate<any[]>` doesn't help.

If I remove the generic type from the `then(..)` function in the Promise-based method, I get largely the same error as when I use the async/await syntax.

I'm using Typescript version 3.7.2

Can anyone explain why this happens and if there's a workaround where I'm still able to use async/await - without having to wrap parts of the code in a promise? I feel like I've tried casting every single type explicitly with no luck so far.

## Update 1

I've reduced the problematic code to this:

```
async filterByParams(
  query: Aggregate<any[]>
) {
  return query;
}
```

While this example basically does nothing, it still causes the compilation error. For some reason, the `async` keyword, seems to just unwrap the `Aggregate` type.

Compare this to the following code, which is similar, but doesn't cause the error:

```
declare class SomeGenericClass<T> {}

async filterByParams(
  query: SomeGenericClass<any[]>
) {
  return query;
}
```

So it seems like the issue is somehow specific to the `Aggregate` type provided by `mongoose`.

[Here's a reproduction of the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fnes9w?file=index.ts)

Comment: It could be related to the fact that you are using `any`. It breaks the chain of typechecks completely. Since query has `any` in itself, it can not evaluate types when you are using `query.match`. Just an assumption, though. It will be better if you provide us with minimal reproducible code on TypeScript playground.

Comment: I tried replacing any with an explicit type, but I just get the error `Type 'SomeDocument[]' is not assignable to type 'Aggregate<SomeDocument[]>'` instead. I will try to reproduce it in an online playground in a moment.

Comment: In promise-base code you do `.then<Aggregate<any[]>>`, that's in fact type-casting the return type manually. Thus when you remove it, error is also raised in promise-base one. The equivalent in async/await base code is just casting it to `as Aggregate<any[]>`. If it raises error, try `as any as Aggregate<any[]>` to force it.

Comment: How `findSomething` is defined? reproducible example would be helpful

Comment: The `findSomething` method doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. I havn't been able to reproduce the issue in a sandbox environment yet.

Comment: There, I've included a reproduction of the issue.

Comment: I've also tried to reproduce this but it works perfectly, even with the declaration of Aggregate from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I havn't found an exact solution, I **have** found an explanation.

I've looked through the [mongoose implementation of the `Aggregate` class](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/dfaf02eccc987fff8421eae7accc6578b919dbac/lib/aggregate.js) and they've added the `then` and `catch`, functions to the Aggregate class to make it act like a promise. This will make the async/await operators treat it like a promise, since they treat any object with a `then`-function as a promise. This is the reason the `Aggregate`-class seems to unwrap when returned from an async method.

For the specific problem at hand, as a workaround, I just moved the async part of the method back to the calling code. Basically like it was before I started tinkering with it. It isn't perfect, but it works.